# merging two tables in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables in s3 under same bucket. one has current data and other has history data  I need to merge these two tables and move it to a different bucket. How can I do that using snoflake? I am new to this so any suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest method would be to create External tables over the two tables and then run a COPY INTO  statement with the target as your new S3 bucket and a select statement that unions both tables.

However, I'm guessing it would be simpler still to do the whole thing entirely in AWS and not involve  Snowflake

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve, can you just put all the files from two tables together? If you need to select out some columns and have some sort of transformation, then using Snowflake to perform a UNION and then write to a different location would do the trick.